# Trigger azure function on list created event - SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, event-receivers

We want to trigger an azure function whenever a new list is created in any site collection in our tenant. So far, we have found webhooks limited to specific list only.

In On-prem env, we can use feature stapler to achieve the same. Do we have something similar available in O365?

Comment: Maybe this is possible using Microsoft Flow, search for it. Just a hint!

Answer (score 0):

We can trigger Azure Functions using Microsoft Flow.

You can refer to the steps provided in this article:

https://gunnarpeipman.com/azure/office365-sharepoint-flow-azure-function/

Comment: But flows are limited to particular site collection/list, i need to make it available for all site collections and lists underneath